# Javascript - Arrays - for-loop to forEach

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach

`Given an array of integers where every value appears twice except one, find the single, non-repeating value.`

`Follow up: do so with O(1) space.`

1) This is incorrect, the idea is to iterate through twice and compare if any value the first time around is not equal to a the 2nd go around. If not, push the non equal value into a new array and return that.

2) Is `forEach` pretty much the same as a `for-loop`?

How could this be rewritten with a `forEach`?

This is not giving me the output I'd like, which for this example,
should just return `4`

**CODE**

```js
 const nonRepeat = arr => {
 
     let newArray = [];

     for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
       for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

         if (arr[i] !== arr[j]) {

           newArray.push(arr[i])

         }
        }
       }
     return newArray
    }

console.log(nonRepeat([2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]));
```

Comment: You code has nothing to do with the task you stated.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert from for loop to forEach loop

**for**

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { [code] }
```

**forEach** eliminates need to create the iterative variable ( for example, i) and always checks every element in the array

```
arr.forEach( [code] )
```

[See Here for Additional Syntax Help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: why so many downvotes? appreciate that. If I write a `forEach` then want to use an `if statement` comparing `arr[i] or i`, how would I do that inside a `forEach` statement?

Comment: @mph85 you should peak at the link I shared.  The index can be access as the second argument to the function.
arr.forEach(function(value, index, arr) { })

Comment: @mph85 No clue on the why the downvote, as they did not comment on why, but you should edit your question and focus it on converting a for loop to a forEach loop.

Comment: hey man, appreciate your response and everything, you think you can delete your post, so I can delete this and post up a revised version? won't let me delete cause you contributed

Comment: @mph85 Instead of creating a new post, you can edit your question to update it.  Also, if I've answered your question, you can mark my response as the solution.